# What is type 'none' for mount points and why are mount points of the same type below /run?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

In Ubuntu 14.04 when executing command mount I get following excerpt

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
```

I do not understand why subdirectories of `/run` are mounted separately inside already mounted parent directory (`/run`) and what `none` filesystem means. My `/etc/fstab` file is empty.

Answer (score 12):

The `none` just means that there is no physical disk partition linked to the mount point you see when issuing the `mount` command. It is used for virtual filesystems like `shm`, `ramfs`, `proc` and `tmpfs`. The `lock`, `shm` and `user` mount points in this example are created separately so they can be mounted with different permissions and settings. Notice the part inside the parentheses?

The reason you don't see these mount configurations in `/etc/fstab` is because they are performed by `upstart` (i.e. during system initialization) and `initramfs-tools`. You can investigate yourself with:

```
grep --color -RE '/run/(lock|shm|user)' /etc 2>/dev/null
```

but more interesting is probably:

```
# grep --color -R 'run_migrate' /etc 2>/dev/null
/etc/init/mounted-var.conf:    run_migrate () {
/etc/init/mounted-var.conf:    run_migrate /var/run /run
/etc/init/mounted-var.conf:    run_migrate /var/lock /run/lock
```

The last part shows that to find the origins of `/run/lock` you need to search for `/var/lock`, for example.

Comment: Correct me if I understand wrong but what you say is: I can mount some partition e.g. /dev/sda1 at /home with some privileges eg.: readonly but then remount part of /home e.g. /home/captcha with privileges read-write. In such scenario /home/capcha is reported by mount as 'none' filesystem but is stored on /dev/sda1 same as rest of the /home partition.

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that it would only allow more restrictive permissions in subset mount points. The 'mount --bind' method for the various /run/ filesystems can be seen in /lib/init/mount-functions.sh Doing a man tmpfs now..

Comment: I do not think that it means it has no partition. None takes place of filesystem type e.g. tmpfs so it would rather mean that there is no any filesystem assigned to this mount point but it does not make any sense.

Comment: What's the use of `df` if it even can't distinguish different filesystems? What if there are two `none` file systems that actually represent two different file systems, and what if the same? How am I to distinguish those?